# How to replace part of URL without knowing it beforehand using sed/awk?

Tags: regex, awk, sed

How do I replace part of url string without knowing beforehand what the string would be ? For example below is Ubuntu mirror. I want to set mirror to my liking.

Basically, I want replace (jp, us provided as an example, I think for every country they have their own ubuntu mirrors).

```bash
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse

deb http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
# deb-src http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
deb http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates multiverse
```

To following.

```bash
deb http://mirror.sg.gs/ubuntu focal multiverse
# deb-src http://mirror.sg.gs/ubuntu focal multiverse
deb http://mirror.sg.gs/ubuntu focal-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://mirror.sg.gs/ubuntu focal-updates multiverse

deb http://mirror.sg.gs/ubuntu focal multiverse
# deb-src http://mirror.sg.gs/ubuntu focal multiverse
deb http://mirror.sg.gs/ubuntu focal-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://mirror.sg.gs/ubuntu focal-updates multiverse

deb http://mirror.sg.gs/ubuntu focal multiverse
# deb-src http://mirror.sg.gs/ubuntu focal multiverse
deb http://mirror.sg.gs/ubuntu focal-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://mirror.sg.gs/ubuntu focal-updates multiverse
```

Possibly with `sed`, `awk`.

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: `(us.)?archive.ubuntu.com` regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy solution for perl:

```
perl -pe 's/([^\s\/]+\.)?archive\.ubuntu\.com/mirror.sg.gs/g'
```

*Explanation: This replaces an *optional* part of (non-space and non-slashes followed by a `.`) before `archive.ubuntu.com` by `mirror.sg.gs`.*

If you prefer sed:

```
sed -E 's#(https?://)[^/]*archive.ubuntu.com#\1mirror.sg.gs#'
```

*Explanation: This sed command replaces everything between `http://` or `https://`, followed by an optional part (of no slashes), ending with `archive.ubuntu.com` with your host.*

Here are the two examples updating `/etc/apt/sources.list` in-place:

```
perl -i -pe 's/([^\s\/]+\.)?archive\.ubuntu\.com/mirror.sg.gs/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
sed -Ei 's#(https?://)[^/]*archive.ubuntu.com#\1mirror.sg.gs#' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

I would however replace everything incl. the URL scheme (http/https/ftp). That's also easier to read:

```
perl -pe 's/\s.*archive\.ubuntu\.com/ http:\/\/mirror.sg.gs/g'
```

Comment: Does not work, it also removes `http://`

Comment: @steffen please remove this answer since it is wrong; claiming the rest would be easy is not a fix

Comment: @Andrew Liso wrote he wants to automate his server installation. For that, he would like to replace the original hosts by the `mirror.sg.gs`. It's a good idea to _keep_ the original URL format (be it with or without trailing slashes). So this answer solves exactly the question. The reason why the original perl command previously removed `http://` was because Liso didn't provide any sample data (which btw is also the reason why 6 people downvoted the question (not me)).

Answer (score 1):

Using any sed:

```
$ sed 's#\([^ ]* http://\)[^ ]*#\1mirror.sg.gs/ubuntu#' file
deb http://mirror.sg.gs/ubuntu focal multiverse
# deb-src http://mirror.sg.gs/ubuntu focal multiverse
deb http://mirror.sg.gs/ubuntu focal-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://mirror.sg.gs/ubuntu focal-updates multiverse

deb http://mirror.sg.gs/ubuntu focal multiverse
# deb-src http://mirror.sg.gs/ubuntu focal multiverse
deb http://mirror.sg.gs/ubuntu focal-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://mirror.sg.gs/ubuntu focal-updates multiverse

deb http://mirror.sg.gs/ubuntu focal multiverse
# deb-src http://mirror.sg.gs/ubuntu focal multiverse
deb http://mirror.sg.gs/ubuntu focal-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://mirror.sg.gs/ubuntu focal-updates multiverse
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution replaces everything between the "\" and the first "" (not including these three ""s), then replaces the first 3 ""s (the "\" and the first "") with temporary "~"s, then removes the remaining "/"s, then replaces the three temporary "~"s with ""s:

```
cat input2.txt | sed 's/\(^.*\/\/\)\([^/]*\)\(.*$\)/\1mirror.sg.gs\3/' | sed 's/\//~/' | sed 's/\//~/' | sed 's/\//~/' | sed 's/\///g' | sed 's/~/\//g'
```